# Use OpenCV to extract palm prints from palms

Tags: python, opencv

Now I want to make a program to extract the main palmprints from the palm, but I don't know how to deal with some of the noise.
This is my step:

**First:**

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('palm.png', -1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (95, 95), 0)
# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=192)
cv2.imshow('division', division)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: output]

***Then*** convert it to black-white image:

```
# white color mask
img = cv2.imread('gray.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
lower = np.uint8([0, 185, 0])
upper = np.uint8([255, 255, 255])
white_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
# gray color mask
lower = np.uint8([169, 169, 169])
upper = np.uint8([198, 198, 198])
gray_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
# combine the mask
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(white_mask, gray_mask)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I got this:

[image: output]

How can I remove these noise and some irrelevant line, especially remove noise around the thumb. And I can extract the main lines in hand like this:

[image: one]

Finally, the three most important lines can be extracted like this:

[image: one]

Comment: Hey, please read the how-to ask and adjust your question to include your attempt at solving your question. This includes code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use edge detection algorithms to find the creaks of palms. I recently used Canny's Edge detection algorithm to extract sketches from manga image. I guess if you can well optimise the image, the algorithm alone can work with a bit of CNN to find the palm only

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below method. Here I try to get only the palm area and applied canny edge to find the palm prints. You can change thresholds according to your need. Hope this helps.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process_image(image_path):
    # Read the image and apply filter to remove noise , convert to gray scale
    image_org = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_org, (5, 5), 0)
    grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #Apply threshold to remove the back ground and get only the palm
    ret, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(grayscale_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU) #
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contour_image = np.zeros_like(thresholded_image)
    cv2.drawContours(contour_image, contours, -1, (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

    #Do some noise removal and gap filling methods and get the mask for the palm
    contour_image = cv2.bitwise_not(contour_image)
    contour_image = cv2.erode(contour_image, None, iterations=1)  # Erode to remove noise
    final_mask = cv2.dilate(contour_image, None, iterations=25)  # dilate to close gaps

    #Apply the mask to get only the palm
    hand_image = cv2.bitwise_and(grayscale_image,grayscale_image,mask = final_mask)

    #Apply canny edge detection to get the edges in palm
    #The threshold you can try different values and check.
    palm_edges = cv2.Canny(hand_image, 25, 60)

    return palm_edges

result = process_image("palm.jpg")
cv2.imwrite("palm_result.jpg",result)
```

output:

[image]